# Is Java Point class getX() or getY() is casted automatically?

Tags: java, casting, double, point

I'm trying to simulate cinematic equations for a physical object, so I want to change velocity every ten milli seconds according to acceleration.here's the part of code which doesn't work for me :(int delay = 10)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Point velocity = new Point();
    Point acceleration = new Point(20.0, 0);
    velocity.setLocation(10, 19);

    w‌​hile (true) { 
        velocity.setLocation(velocity.getX() +
            acceleration.getX() * 10 / 1000.0, 19);
        System.out.println(velocity.getX());
    }
}
```

It's unusual that this line doesn't change the velocity's x or y.(and acceleration's x is 20 and it's y is 40.0 ; in case their range makes a difference that I doubt it does)
When I print acceleration.getX() * delay / 1000.0 it prints 0.0 and when I try printing it after replacing acceleration.getX() with its amount it prints the real amount.

Does anyone know what's wrong with this code?
Is getX() casted or something automatically?

Comment: Can you provide a verifiable example?

Comment: No, please provide a [mcve] in the question. Something we can run.

Comment: "When I print `acceleration.getX() * delay / 1000.0` it prints `0.0`", please provide more details as I cannot replicate this. Remember however that `Point` stores values as integers, so if `acceleration.getX()` returns `40` and `delay = 10` (as you say) then `acceleration.getX() * delay / 1000.0` evaluates to `0.2`. This will be floored to `0` when assigned using `Point.setLocation(double, double)`

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in

[Point Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html)

The values that define the point are stored as ints so if the double you want to store is between 0.0 and 1.0 (as is the case on your example) it gets cast to a 0.